# How can I implement Nordic Semiconductor DFU on .NET MAUI?

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, ios17, dfu, nordic-semi

I am currently migrating my application from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI.
I need to implement a [DFU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Device_Firmware_Upgrade) process from the mobile app to a [BLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy) device, and I have issues with the [Laerdal.Dfu](https://github.com/Laerdal/Laerdal.Dfu) NuGet package on .NET MAUI for the iOS 17.

I've added [my issue](https://github.com/Laerdal/Laerdal.Dfu/issues/27) on the package's repository, but it doesn't have any answers...

Is there a sample or a workaround for implementing DFU on .NET MAUI?

Comment: The essential information is expected to be in the Stack Overflow question itself.